# My PyCFunction works the first time but leads to a segfault after successive iterations

Tags: python, numpy, python-extensions

I want to write a python object in c that holds a numpy vector (two actually, but just one in this minimal example).

To begin with, I just want to create an object with a numpy array and see that I can add one to all the array-elements in a loop. But even this causes weird (reproducible) behavior and segfaults.

Here is what happens (REPL):

```
from rletest import Rle
r = Rle(range(1, 10))
r.runs
# array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
r.add()
r.runs
# array([ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.])
r.add()
fish: 'python' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

I can work around this like so:

```
... r2 = r.add()
>>> r3 = r2.add()
>>> r4 = r3.add()
>>> r4.runs
array([ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.])
```

I suspect this has something to do with reference counting? I am a complete newb to this and clueless. Any help appreciated. This function (or my use of it) is likely the offender:

```
static PyObject * Rle_add(Rle* self)
{
  int N = (int)PyArray_DIM(self->runs, 0);
  double *x = (double*)PyArray_DATA(self->runs);
  add(x, N);
  return (PyObject *)self;
}
```

It changes the array in-place for speed, but that should not lead to the bug, as you see from the work-around above.

Below follows my code so this is reproducible.

I have the following files:

test_rle.c:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include "structmember.h"
#include "add.h"

/* static PyObject *add(PyObject *self, PyObject *args); */

typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyObject *runs; /* run lengths */
} Rle;


static void
Rle_dealloc(Rle* self)
{
    Py_XDECREF(self->runs);
    Py_TYPE(self)->tp_free((PyObject*)self);
}


static PyObject *
Rle_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{

  printf("New was called! New was called! New was called!\n");
    Rle *self;
    PyObject *rs, *vs;

    import_array();

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &rs))
      return NULL;

    PyObject *runs = PyArray_FROM_OTF(rs, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_IN_ARRAY);

    self = (Rle *)type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
    if (self != NULL) {

        self->runs = runs;
        if (self->runs == NULL) {
            Py_DECREF(self);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    printf("Reference count after new: %d\n", Py_REFCNT(self));
    return (PyObject *)self;
}

static int
Rle_init(Rle *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
  printf("Init was called! Init was called! Init was called!\n");

  printf("Reference count after init: %d\n", Py_REFCNT(self));
    return 0;
}


static PyMemberDef Rle_members[] = {
    {"runs", T_OBJECT_EX, offsetof(Rle, runs), 0,
     "Run lengths"},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};

static PyObject * Rle_add(Rle* self)
{
  int N = (int)PyArray_DIM(self->runs, 0);
  double *x = (double*)PyArray_DATA(self->runs);
  add(x, N);
  return (PyObject *)self;
}


static PyMethodDef Rle_methods[] = {
    {"add", (PyCFunction)Rle_add, METH_NOARGS,
     "Add 1 to the runs"
    },
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};

static PyTypeObject RleType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    "rle.Rle",             /* tp_name */
    sizeof(Rle),             /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                         /* tp_itemsize */
    (destructor)Rle_dealloc, /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                         /* tp_print */
    0,                         /* tp_getattr */
    0,                         /* tp_setattr */
    0,                         /* tp_reserved */
    0,                         /* tp_repr */
    0,                         /* tp_as_number */
    0,                         /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                         /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                         /* tp_hash  */
    0,                         /* tp_call */
    0,                         /* tp_str */
    0,                         /* tp_getattro */
    0,                         /* tp_setattro */
    0,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT |
        Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,   /* tp_flags */
    "Rle objects",           /* tp_doc */
    0,                         /* tp_traverse */
    0,                         /* tp_clear */
    0,                         /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                         /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                         /* tp_iter */
    0,                         /* tp_iternext */
    Rle_methods,             /* tp_methods */
    Rle_members,             /* tp_members */
    0,                         /* tp_getset */
    0,                         /* tp_base */
    0,                         /* tp_dict */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                         /* tp_dictoffset */
    (initproc)Rle_init,      /* tp_init */
    0,                         /* tp_alloc */
    Rle_new,                 /* tp_new */
};

static PyModuleDef rletestmodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "rletest",
    "Example module that creates an extension type.",
    -1,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_rletest(void)
{
    PyObject* m;

    if (PyType_Ready(&RleType) < 0)
        return NULL;

    m = PyModule_Create(&rletestmodule);
    if (m == NULL)
        return NULL;

    Py_INCREF(&RleType);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "Rle", (PyObject *)&RleType);
    return m;
}
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name="rle", version="1.0",
      ext_modules=[Extension("rletest", ["test_rle.c", "add.c"])])
```

add.h

```
void add(double *x, int N);
```

add.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(double *x, int N) {
  int n;

  for (n = 0; n < N; n++) {
    x[n] += 1.0;
  }
}
```

Place it all in the same folder and run

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

to build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return (PyObject *)self;
```

You now have an extra reference to `self` so you need to `incref` it. As it is you don't assign the return value so Python immediately `decrefs` it and `r` ceases to exist.

(Your workround avoids the immediate `decref` but I'm surprised it does just cause a segmentation fault later.)